# Present Perfect Continuous - effect

Tags: tense, present-perfect, aspect, perfect-continuous

Take the following sentence:

> I have been learning for two hours.

Can this imply that I am not learning now? I'm tired and I want this sentence to show the effect that learning has on me.

Or it is better to say "I have learned for two hours"?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> I **have been learning** for two hours.

The second sentence, "I have learned for two hours," is **not specific with regards to timeframe**. You could have learned for two hours earlier today, yesterday, or last month. "I **have been learning**" makes it clear that the action of learning **began in the past, and continued until right now.** What the sentence does not specify is *whether you will keep learning in the future*. To make that clear, you need to give context, for instance:

> I have been learning for two hours, **and I'm taking a break**.

Compare that with the following:

> I have been learning for two hours, **and I need a break**.

The first implies that you are not learning at the moment, while the second does. Bottom line, do *not* use "I **have learned**," and rather come up with a specific sentence incorporating the phrase "I **have been** learning."